# How to parse UTC format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzzz" in to "MM/dd/yyyy"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, utc

I am trying to *convert* a `DateTime` `string`(UTC format) which I am getting from API. The initial `string` is

`2019-06-24T13:24:39+1770`

I tried using code:

```
DateTime Dt;

DateTime.TryParseExact(
   DtString, 
   new string[] { 
     "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzzz", 
     "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
     "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", 
     "yyyy-MMM-dd", 
     "MM/dd/yyyy",
   CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
   DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, 
   out Dt);
```

Or

```
DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

It gives me runtime error

> string was not recognized as valid datetime

Comment: What does `+1770` in the `2019-06-24T13:24:39+1770` mean, please?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I believe it's timezone

Comment: Dates have no format. They are binary values. This is *NOT* the ISO8601 format though. `=1770` is not a valid offset. Valid offsets look like `+01:00`, `-07:00` or `+05:30`

Comment: It is `zzzz` value that is defined by ISO 8601 for date format.

Comment: @Priya no it's not. Valid offsets are `+01:00`, `-07:00` or `+05:30`. What is `1770` supposed to be? Minutes? In that case that's an offset of 29.5 *hours*

Comment: In any case, the correct type for time with an offest is [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netframework-4.8#methods), not `DateTime`. *Both* `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTimeOffset.Parse` can parse the ISO8601 format without even a format specifier. `DateTime.Parse("2019-06-27T15:12:24.3032748+03:00")` just works, and so does `DateTimeOffset.Parse("2019-06-27T15:12:24.3032748+03:00")`

Comment: Also, `UTC` is not a format, it's a timezone - [Coordinated Universal Time.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)

Comment: @Priya I have to agree with Panagiotis, DateTimeOffset is what is required and the offset portion is not valid. 

According yo ISO 8601, if the time being described is one hour ahead of UTC, such as the time in Luanda, the zone designator would be "+01:00", "+0100", or simply "+01".

However, 1770 is invalid, offset range from -12 to +14, so that value must be incorrect OR something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to parse the date as a string and then use the parsed results' groups to format the date the way you want.

it's the most optimal solution but it should definitely solve your issue.

Comment: No, when the right format has been discovered, `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact` is almost certain to be a *much* better solution than regular expressions. The framework provides the appropriate methods - there's no point in using a regular expression here. The problem is that the input data doesn't make sense at the moment (with an offset of +1770), and that's completely independent of the code used to parse it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree, thanks for the correction. My excuses for providing a bad solution.